# jquery or javascript active element on foreground, lock background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a layer that is presented by a logic var.

that layer is just a hidden div - how do I make it so the layer is the only element that can be interacted with on the page when it is visible?

thanks!

Update:

used a full size div in the background with a transparent gif - works in firefox, but not IE - thoughts?

```
#overlay {
    background-image: url('../images/transparent.gif');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:8999;
    display:none;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left:0;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach is to put a semi-transparent element over your whole page, but under your modal window that contains your focus element.  JQuery doesn't have this built in, so you can either create your own using that approach or use a [JQuery plugin](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/).

**UPDATE:**

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/YP4hn/) a fiddle based on the comment discussion.  I've tested this and it works in IE8, Firefox 3.5.15, and Chrome 12.0.742.112.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div>test</div>
<input/>

<div class="modalWindow ">
    foo:
    <input/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlay {
    opacity:.1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=10);
    background-color: black;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:8999;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left:0;
    position:fixed;
}

.modalWindow {
    z-index:9000;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: great, this is how I'll have to do it.I can't user a plugin in this instance.

Comment: @Jason May it go well for you :)

Comment: @Jason It's hard to tell without seeing your code.  Do you have a fiddle where I can see and test what you are trying?  **EDIT:** Oops, just saw you edited the question.

Comment: /* for IE (note: will only work reliably on positioned elements) */  filter:alpha(opacity=60);  /* for Mozilla */ -moz-opacity: 60%;  /* CSS3 standard */  opacity:0.6;

Comment: got it working, just had to move the div to immediately after the body open

Comment: @Jason Glad you got it working.  [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/YP4hn/) a fiddle just in case it might help (it uses background color rather than an image for transparency).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are creating a modal dialog. You can use jQueryUI to handle this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

You can use a [jQuery UI Modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Comment: I was trying to do it without a plugin, but my initial thought was a modal window as well.

Comment: To construct a modal without plugins you can create a `position:fixed` div with height/width at 100% that lays on top of the rest of the page with the modal div on top of that.  If you can go without a custom solution you might also consider a more lightweight plugin: [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

Answer (score 0):

[BlockUI jQuery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) is an alternative to using jQuery UI modals. This is a neat demo that shows how you can disable a specific background element in a slightly different fashion: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Comment: yeah, unfortunately this is an area where I was unable to use a plugin. using the full size transparent window div was the quickest, and dirtiest was of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

*To answer your question update:*

You could make your gif transparent with CSS2.1 and CSS3 because there are problems with transparent gifs/pngs in some browsers:

```
#overlay {
    background-image: url('../images/transparent.gif');
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:8999;
    display:none;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left:0;
    position:fixed;
    /* for IE, the filter only works reliably on positioned elements */
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); -moz-opacity: 40%; opacity: 0.4; 
}
```